# using useRef in input to avoid re render in appication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

I want to implement useRef so that the component in which my input tag is should not re-render on value change. If we use useState it will re-render the entire component on every key pressed.

This is how we usually do it but this will re-render the entire component on every change.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
return(
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />   
)
```

I want to do this using useRef to avoid it

```
const name = useRef("");
const handleName = (e) => {
   name.current = e.target.value
 };

return(
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={name.current.value} onChange={handleName} />   
)
```

but it's not working for some reason?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the re-render?

Comment: I am learning react hooks and I think why to re-render the entire component if we can achieve this using useRef with re-render I think? I may be wrong!

Comment: The `input` element takes care of re-rendering itself on every value change, you don't need to pass the updated value to it, it handles it's own state.

Answer (score 3):

Change your input tag to this (inside JSX):

```
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ref={name} onChange={handleName} />
```

Instead of `value={name.current.value}`  use `ref={name}`. It should fix the issue.

**Full code :**

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const name = useRef('');

  const handleName = (e) => {
     name.current = e.target.value
     document.getElementById('test').innerText = name.current
   };
  
  return(
    <>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ref={name} onChange={handleName} />   
     <p id='test'></p>

     </>
  )
  
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is working as I said but can we display the current value of input value like in p tag using this.

Comment: You can try this by giving an ```id``` to your p tag.

 const handleName = (e) => {
     name.current = e.target.value
     document.getElementById('test').innerText = name.current
   };
  
  return(
    <>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ref={name} onChange={handleName} />   
     <p id='test'></p>

     </>

Comment: either the above way or you can try the ```dangerouslySetInnerHTML``` property of react. (I have updated my answer using the ```id``` approach)

you can check here for more info about it - https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid rendering on change, you can just pass ref to the input element. and whenever required you can get the value from ref as used in the handleSubmit method below. Html input element will maintain its state:

```
    const nameRef = useRef(null);
const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log(nameRef.current.value);
};

return(
   <input type="text" ref={nameRef}  placeholder="Name" />   
)
```

Comment: const nameRef = useRef(null);
const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log(nameRef.current.value);
};

return(
   <input type="text" ref={nameRef}  placeholder="Name" />
)

Comment: This is working as it suppose to be but if you have to give a p tag that displays the current value of the input tag then it's not working as    <p>{nameRef.current.value} </p>

Comment: if you want to display the value on change then you need to render and maintain the name state

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue in your code comes from:

```
const name = useRef("");
```

The value of `name` here is an empty string, and can not be used to refer to a DOM element. Then applying `name.current.value` doesn't work as you might expect.
Using `const name = useRef()` will enable us to refer to the input element by assigning `name` to the input's `ref` attribute.

Having said that, I would suggest modifying your code as follows:

```
const name = useRef();
const handleName = (e) => {
   name.current.value = e.target.value
 };

return(
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ref={name} onChange={handleName} />   
)
```

Update: Other approaches for optimizing re-rendering on every keystroke can be found [here](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#optimizing-re-rendering-on-every-keystroke).